# Is it possible to change the module lookup path for React Native?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I want to, e.g, have `require('foo/bar')` be able to find `myProjectRoot/src/foo/bar`.

- Webpack has `resolve`
- Jest has `moduleDirectories`
- Ordinary Node.js has [app-module-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path)

I was hoping the latter would Just Work with React Native, but it [Doesn't](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968). Is it possible some other way?

Comment: If you're calling the dependency from inside your `src/` directory, you just need to prefix it with a `.`. E.g. `require('./foo/bar')`. Or is that what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. For files in the same directory, that's easy of course, but the app I'm working on has several layers of folder nesting, and it's also easier to move things around during refactoring when you don't have to change a bunch of imports.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the beginning of bar.js

`/**
 * @providesModule bar
 */`

then simply using:

`import Bar from 'bar';`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that; I didn't know about it. However, it doesn't suit my needs; I want to be able to reference a whole folder and all its descendants without having to add something to each file.

Comment: I don't know it neither.